# Different outputs based on different links (Ajax)

Tags: ajax, parameters

I am sure this is a common question, but since I'm really new to Ajax I couldn't figure out which solution is the best for me and how to execute this:

I have a page with several links, and a div in the middle of the page in which the output of the ajax request is shown.
By now I have successfully used this ajax function for one link:

```
function loadXMLDoc()
{
  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
      document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","history.html");
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

However, I want to show different outputs based on the links clicked.
These are some of my links:

```
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Link 1 - History</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Link 2 - Economics</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Link 3 - Physics</a></li>
```

I want to get and show different html files based on the links clicked, But I don't know how to execute it.

I guess it is done by passing parameters, but I don't know what to do in order make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you could do:

```
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#" onclick="loadXMLDoc(1)">Link 1 - History</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#" onclick="loadXMLDoc(2)">Link 2 - Economics</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#" onclick="loadXMLDoc(3)">Link 3 - Physics</a></li>
```

and:

```
function loadXMLDoc(doc) {
    // ...
    xmlhttp.open("GET","history.php?q="+doc);
    // ...
}
```

And output a different thing on the server side, depending on the `q` parameter. (or, do it in JS: if 1, open "page1.html"; if 2, open "page2.html", etc.

---

However, I'd suggest that you don't reinvent the wheel, and use a JS library such as jQuery; it's gonna make your life a lot easier. For example, with jQuery, you could just use the following:

```
function loadXMLDoc(doc) {
    $.post('ajax/test.html?q=' + doc, function(data) {
        $('#myDiv').html(data);
    });
}
```

This might look a bit foreign at first, but it's much more convenient than what you have. Another highlight is that you can save yourself the `onclick` attribute and the resulting mixture HTML and JS.

```
// no need to use onclick
$('.menu-item').eq(0).click(function() { loadXML(1); });
$('.menu-item').eq(1).click(function() { loadXML(2); });
$('.menu-item').eq(2).click(function() { loadXML(3); });
```

---

If you only need to do a few stuff within a project, you save yourself several kilobytes and use single-task libraries from http://microjs.com/# .

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, I will have to learn how it is used exactly and hopefully it will make things easier.

Comment: @amiregelz - sorry for the wall of text! :) since it seems you're just starting out, I've tried to provide a lot of food for thought so you have a good starting point :)